# Pass parameters to a new generic class created in a abstract class

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have an abstract class that I use to set default values in a WCF proxy. I want all my other proxies to derive from this class passing in the service client that was generated when they added a service reference. Therefore I have the following

```
public abstract class ProxyFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    protected BasicHttpBinding BasicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    public abstract T GetTranslationServiceClient();

    protected ProxyFactory()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
    }

    protected T CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint(string uri)
    {
        var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
        return new T(BasicHttpBinding, address);
    }
}
```

So for instance if you had a project and added a service reference to WCF service called `MyService` you would have a generated class called `MyServiceClient`. Then I would create a new class called `MyServiceProxy` that would derive from this class where T would be of type `MyServiceClient`. This would allow me to have all my common configuration in done in the base and the only code I would need to write is an override for the `CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint` with the url of the service.

```
public override MyServiceImplClient GetMyServiceClient()
{
    return CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint("http://localhost/MyServices/MyServiceImpl.svc");
}
```

The this derived class will be used as a factory so calling clients would create a new instance and invoke `CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint` to get a preconfigured WCF proxy

The problem is the line `return new T(BasicHttpBinding, address);` in the `CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint` method of the abstract class. It will not allow me to pass the parameters to the constructor. How can this be done?

Comment: It may sometimes be a better option to introduce an interface with an init method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to create your returned instance with [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx):

```
protected T CreateClientForServiceAtEndpoint(string uri)
{
    var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
    return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), BasicHttpBinding, address);
}
```

And there is no need for the `where T : new()` restriction.

EDIT: After Marc's comment

Because there is now why to say anything about a `T`'s constructor (other then `new()`) the `Activator.CreateInstance` can throw if the supplied `T` does not have the right constructor.

But you can add some additional guide to your API users with the
creation of an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class ServiceImplClientBase
{
    public ServiceImplClientBase(BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding, EndpointAddress endpointAddress)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And use it as the type restriction: `where T : ServiceImplClientBase`. But it can just provide a hint for the need of the constructor because derived types can declare the base constructor as private or protected.

Comment: The second example will not work - that says nothing about the constructors of T